# Plot a function inside of another function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, boundary-conditions

I want to plot y[x] vs. x[t]:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ClearAll
eqns = {(x[t]*y'[x]) + (3*a*y[x]) == (9*b*((x'[t]*y[x]^m)/x[t])), 
   x'[t]^2 == ((y[x] + f)*x[t]^2) + d, x[1] == 1, y[1] == 1};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {x, y}, {t, 1, 10}, {m, a, b, f, d}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[m, a, b, f, d][t], y[m, a, b, f, d][x]} /. sol], {t, 1, 10},{x, 1, 10}], {{m, 1}, 0, 3, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 1}, 1, 5, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 60, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f, 1}, 0, 60, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 1}, 0, 60, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

a,b,f are positive but d is negative parameters

Comment: Please troubleshoot this stepwise. Get rid of the manipulate and get the function to plot on a single value of t and x, then come back to the more complex parts. Note that `Plot` produces a 2D plot as a function of a single variable, so it does not take two variable specifications, as indicated by the error you receive within Manipulate. You'd probably want some form of `ParametricPlot` instead.

Comment: Even earlier that that, your `ParametricNDSolve` doesn't work either. Your `x` function should always be written as `x[t]` even as an argument to `y`, so `y[x[t]]`. It is important that you try to get the pieces working before you jump into deeper waters with Manipulate and Plot. Also pay attention to the errors you get; do not suppress the output with `;` until you are very sure that everything is working.

Comment: Once you get those going, NDSolve is still unhappy with your equation, reporting that "There are fewer dependent variables, {x[t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined." I will leave that to you to pursue further.

Answer (score 2):

You can not define y[x[t]], define this a y[t]. You may rewrite y later on. Further "ClearAll" without arguments does nothing. Working Precision is on many machine approx 16. So " WorkingPrecision -> 15" seems unnecessary.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {(x[t]*y'[t]) + (3*a*y[t]) == (9*b*((x'[t]*y[t]^m)/x[t])), 
   x'[t]^2 == ((y[t] + f)*x[t]^2) + d, x[1] == 1, y[1] == 1};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {x, y}, {t, 1, 10}, {m, a, b, f, d}];
```

In the plot command, ",{x, 1, 10}" is wrong. As the range of x and y is very different, it is better to draw them separately:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x[m, a, b, f, d][t] /. sol, {t, 1, 10}], {{m, 1}, 0, 3, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 1}, 1, 5, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[y[m, a, b, f, d][t] /. sol, {t, 1, 500}], {{m, 1}, 0, 3, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 1}, 1, 5, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 1}, 0, 60, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: To plot `y[t]` versus `x[t]`, use `ParametricPlot[{x[m, a, b, f, d][t], y[m, a, b, f, d][t]} /. sol, {t, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: I have this error. Syntax::bktmop: Expression "<<1>>]" has no opening "[".

I'm running with Macbook Catalina OS

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I did not copy all lines. It is corrected now.

Comment: m = 0; a = 1.3; d = -0.002; b = 0.2; f = 0.69;
ParametricPlot[{x[m, a, b, f, d][t], y[m, a, b, f, d][t]} /. sol, {t, 
  1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]

Comment: Bob, it is not working even y vs x